# Constantly Moving A Button Back And Forth In Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

The goal is to move a button from one `div` to another on click and then back to the other if clicked again and continue to do so each time it is clicked.

My problem is that the code I shared only runs once; what I need is for this behavior to run continuously.

```js
const ham = document.getElementById('ham');
const mh = document.querySelector('.mobile-header');
const hc = document.querySelector('.header .content');

ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-is-toggled');                  
    mh.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', ham);
    
    ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
        hc.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', ham);
    });
});
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header content">
     <span id="ham">X</span>
  </div>
</header>

<nav>
  <div class="mobile-header"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please share also your html, also the first issue I see here is that like this you'll add more and more click listeners doing the same or multiple things on each click. So you'll do mh.insertadjacent and hc.insert.. at the same time and that multiple times depending on how often ham has been clicked.

Comment: what am I doing wrong that it only works once? Should I put it all into a function and call it when the button is clicked?

Comment: Please share also your HTML, not only the JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a class to body, but there is no if-statement. See this example:

```js
const ham = document.getElementById('ham');
const mh = document.querySelector('.mobile-header');

ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('nav-is-toggled');
  if (document.body.classList.contains('nav-is-toggled')) {
    mh.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', ham);
  } else {
    mh.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', ham);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="mobile-header">mobile-header</div>
<div id="ham">ham</div>
```

Comment: so bad... `classList.toggle()` return a boolean value, Using an `classList.contains()' is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way :

```js
const 
  ham = document.getElementById('ham')
, mh  = document.querySelector('.mobile-header')
, hc  = document.querySelector('.header.content')
  ;
ham.onclick = () =>
  {
  let DomObj = document.body.classList.toggle('nav-is-toggled') ? mh : hc
  DomObj.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', ham)
  }
```

```css
header, nav { 
  height     : 3em;
  background : lightsteelblue;
  margin     : 1em;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header content">
      <span id="ham">XxxxxxxxxX</span>
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <div class="mobile-header"></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two divs, and add js.
make two buttons, one in each div.

```
div2.style.display = block
let button1 = //select the button inside the 1st div
let div1 = //select the 1st div
let button2 = //…
let div2 = /…
button1.addEventListener(`click`, function(){div1.style.display = `none`
div2.style.display = block
})

button2.addEventListener(`click`, function(){div2.style.display = `none`
div1.style.display = block
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).